# What is the AWS Access Key ID/AWS Secret Access key?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to execute Exercise 1.1 in the AWS Certified Solutions Architect Study Guide, and am stymied right away.

It says to "Install (if necessary) and configure te AWS CLI on your local system...."

I don;t know if it is installed, adn have no idea what to do here, but I will press on.

It also says "To get you started, here are some basice CLI commets:"

```
aws s3 ls
aws s3 mb <bucketname>
aws s3 cp /path/to/file.txt s3://bucketname
```

OK.  I type aws s3 ls and get an error saying that my access keys aren't set up and that I can fix this my running aws configure.

I run aws configure and am asked for: 1) AWS Access Key ID, 2) AWS Secret Access Key, 3) Default region name, and 4) Default output format.

I have no idea whatsoever what any of this is.  i recall having set up a key pair at some point in the not to distant past, and manage to find a reference to it.  I put in the fingerprint of the public key in the first, and manage to find the file that I was sent for the secret key, and cut and paste it.  But it has a bunch of lines, so cut and pasting it doesn't work.  I really doubt that this is the right stuff, anyway, but I have no idea what would be the right stuff.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Access key and secret are your credentials to hit the AWS API. You've to create an IAM user (as best practice), and then created the access key and secret. And then you've to configure the details using `aws configure`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

[Configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)